# Left to Right Binding Order in Let Form

Tags: clojure, let, destructuring

I am working through an example of destructuring in the [Joy of Clojure](http://www.joyofclojure.com/), and I cam across an example that surprised me.  Both of these produce the same output:

```
(let [range-vec (vec (range 10)) [a b c & more :as all] range-vec]
        (println "a b c: " a b c)
        (println "more: " more)
        (println "all: " all))

(let [range-vec (vec (range 10))]
    (let [[a b c & more :as all] range-vec]
        (println "a b c: " a b c)
        (println "more: " more)
        (println "all: " all)))
```

Now initially the first form countered my intuition because, thinking that binding and precedence happened from left to right, that range-vec would not be defined before assigning to "all".  I the second form, range-vec has already been defined, and then assigned to all in the second let statement, which seems to follow the rules I know so far.  When do I know when a symbol has been bound and the order in which that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Clojure documentation](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5Bbindings%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29):

> The bindings are sequential, so each binding can see the prior bindings.

Are you a Lisp or Scheme programmer? Clojure `let` is like `let*` in CL or Scheme in this regard.

Comment: I'm new to lisps in general so I'm not familia with `let*`.  So bindings go from left to right, not right to left?

Comment: Yes, bindings are left to right. So your two versions are equivalent.